# Diff between Normal Postback by a button Click and a postback using __doPostBack in javascript ?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, dopostback

Question is the title itself.

```
 __doPostBack('<%=btnABC.UniqueID %>', '') and 

  onClick="Button1_Click"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could refer to the following threads which discuss same:
[What is the difference between client browser's submit mechanism and the ASP.NET postback mechanism?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635855/what-is-the-difference-between-client-browsers-submit-mechanism-and-the-asp-net)
&

[Button click/page submit from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848822/button-click-page-submit-from-javascript)